# get filename from uri on activityResult() in android studio

Tags: android, android-intent

I need filename from the file path of the DICOM image which is downloaded and selected from the gallery to load in imageView of android studio.

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Comment: @Piyush i get uri of the downloaded image as====>content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/22 , hence getting exception file not found  since 22 is the file name

Comment: So are not able to find real path?

Comment: @Piyush No sir, not able find the real image name. i get 22 as image name which shows exception file not found

Comment: First have you checked that you have granted runtime permission?

Comment: Check [this code](https://justpaste.it/264lt). I was using before.

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working, will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: As of Android 10 file paths are worthless unless inside you app's private storage, you need to work with URI's and FileDescriptors instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get filename from uri from onActivityResult.

```
Uri uri= data.getData();
File file= new File(uri.getPath());
file.getName();
```

Comment: this code is correct for image in gallery (which is not downloaded).  Downloaded image's uri is different on activityResult content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/22

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_REQUEST) {
            if(data != null){
               String name = new File(data.getData().getPath()).getName();
            }
        }
    }
}
```